# Ranking based on two measures in Power BI

Tags: dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling, ranking

I have a matrix visual in power bi which shows post code and suburb as rows and event as column which has three events for example phone release events and it has values based on two measures which are total orders and delayed %. I need top 20 based on those 2 measures, which are highest orders and highest delayed % like a ranking.

I tried this
Ranking = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Data'[Post Code], 'Data'[Suburb]), ([Orders] + ([Delayed %]*100)), , DESC, Dense)

Comment: add a data sample and explain how the ranking should work. Right now, your question is not clear. Edit your question to add the additional info, do not do that in a comment. Post a comment to alert the people following the question.